# Table cell not honouring min-width and max-width in a fixed table

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table with fixed layout. In my application I need **td** to be always of same width which is not happening. These **tds** are created dynamically in the real application. I have created a stub in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alowsarwar/1qr6og6L/ .

### HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered responsive-qtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
       th1
      </th>
      <th style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
       th2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="qtable-cell" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell;">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </td>
      <td class="qtable-cell" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="qtable-cell" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell;">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

      </td>
      <td class="qtable-cell" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell;">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

### css

```
.responsive-qtable {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: block;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

td{
   border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a div inside your td with your desired dimensions.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri The div takes my desired width but the td is more than I desired. In this case div and td should be of same width

Comment: Use display:table; for .responsive-qtable in place of display:block;

Comment: @RajanBenipuri No It does not work, now the td width is even more than desired 300px. Pls experiment in the jsfiddle to see changes

Comment: I am really sorry mate. I am right now using a mobile device so can't see the desired result on jsfiddle or codepen (and its a bit too much as well testing codes on mobile) I am giving you some wild hints based on your question and that is why I am commenting.